# Room Android - How to handle database version upgrade

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am reading about Android Architecture components **Room** and wanted to know if there is there anything in Room equivalent to onUpgrade in SQLiteOpenHelper method available.

```
@Override
 public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase database, final int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {}
```

Comment: see [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions.html

```
 Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MyDb.class, "database-name")
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2,MIGRATION_1_3, MIGRATION_2_3).build();

    static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `Fruit` (`id` INTEGER, "
                    + "`name` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
        }
    };

    static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Book "
                    + " ADD COLUMN pub_year INTEGER");
        }
    };

   static final Migration MIGRATION_1_3 = new Migration(1, 3) {
            @Override
            public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Book "
                        + " ADD COLUMN pub_year INTEGER");
            }
        };
```

Comment: how it will handle if user directly goes from 1 to 3

Comment: @ManishButola I have updated in answer, please check

Comment: I think we don't need to explicitly handle for 1 to 3 as 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 will handle everything if user goes from 1 to 3

Answer (score -4):

Use following library with your own sqlite file in assets folder so there is no boiler plate code for creation tables

compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'